# Configure hostname for Windows Server agent

Tags: newrelic

We are monitoring multiple Windows machines with the same hostnames using the New Relic server monitoring agent. It seems that there is no way to disambiguate between these two machines. Only one shows up in the New Relic dashboard. Only one shows up.

Is there any way to configure this scenario in the agent or elsewhere? E.g. to give one server an alias or something?

Answer (score 0):

While we don't recommend this because you can break the linkages between the apps the reported hostname in the UI, you can change this via a registry key. To rectify the problem an alternate hostname can be assigned to one or more of the hosts in New Relic via the registry. Here is how:

1. Open the registry editor.
2. Browse to : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\New Relic\Server Monitor\`.
3. Add or Update the `Host` string with a new value.
4. Restart the `New Relic Windows Server Monitor Service`.